# Error updating Sharepoint List item, when called from web service

Tags: ajax, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm using ajax to call a webservice which updates a sharepoint list.

It works when I call the code from unit tests, but running the code in a browser causes an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.GetContextWeb(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.get_Current()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update()

My code to update the list item is:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(path))
                {
                    SPList userProfile = web.Lists[userList];
                    SPQuery qry = new SPQuery
                    {
                        Query =
                            "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>" +
                            accountName +
                            "</Value></Eq></Where><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='LastUpdated' /><FieldRef Name='Reason' /></ViewFields>"
                    };

                    SPListItemCollection spListItemCollection = userProfile.GetItems(qry);

                    if (spListItemCollection.Count == 1)
                    {
                        //edit user
                        SPListItem item = spListItemCollection[0];
                        item["Updated"] = DateTime.Now;
                        item["Reason"] = updateReason;
                        item.Update();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

It errors on item.Update();

Comment: When you run the unit test, does it execute under the same account credentials as the web service does? I wonder if it's a security issue.

Comment: It uses the same credentials for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with security. The following line needs to be added (although not ideal)

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
```

I also removed the line

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
```

and changed the SPSite and SPWeb to not use "using".

Comment: Two things: first, it would be best to set AllowUnsafeUpdates back to false after item.Update. Second, the usings on SPSite and SPWeb should not be causing any errors. If you do not use using, then be sure to explicitly call Dispose on SPSite and SPWeb, otherwise you're application will leak memory. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248(office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/02/10/userprofilemanager-userexists-and-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object.aspx):

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    if (context.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] == null)
        context.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] = site.RootWeb;
    if (context.Items["Microsoft.Office.ServerContext"] == null)
        context.Items["Microsoft.Office.ServerContext"] = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
}
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful, it showed me the same SPSecurityException error that I had before I used SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
so I knew I had to remove this line.